# Teams in tournament problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have a practical math problem that I can't solve by myself.
The problem is probably already solved by other people but I can't think of any
Google 
search words.
If somebody knows a solution or is willing to try and solve it that would be
awesome.
I need a algorithm to plan some kind of tournament. I wrote an algorithm in
Mathematica 
that tries randomly to find the best option but it would take thousands of years
to solve the 
problem that way.

**This is the problem:**
There are a total of p people, they are distributed over teams.
Ever round g different games are played, t teams play game A, t teams play game
B etc. for 
all g games. (So the total number of teams is t*g.)

For instance:
g = 5, t=3 (so there a 15 teams)

....................Round 1......................Round 2............. Round 3
etc. etc.

Game A:.....1 vs 2 vs 3..............4 vs 8 vs 15...............etc.

Game B:.....4 vs 5 vs 6.................1 vs 7 vs 12................etc.

Game C:.....7 vs 8 vs 9.................2 vs 10 vs 13..............etc.

Game D:....10 vs 11 vs 12...........3 vs 6 vs 14.................etc.

Game E:.....13 vs 14 vs 15...........5 vs 9 vs 11................etc.

**Rule 1: Every team has to play every game at least once,** but no more than
strictly necessary 
to make all rules work.

**Rule 2: Every team has to play against every other team**,so team 1 has to play
team 2,3,4...15 
(team 2 has to play team all other teams etc. etc.). If team 1 already played
team 12, they can 
only play each other again if it's strictly necessary to make the rules work. In
the example 
above there was a match "1 vs 7 vs 12" so later on match "1 vs 12 vs 9" may only
happen is 
there is no other option.

Rule 3: If a team has to play a game more than once, it's better if there is a
pause between 
those games (so not in successive rounds).

Rule 4: If a team has to play a other team more than once, it's better if there
is a pause 
between those games (so not in successive rounds).

Rule 5: If the people can't be distributed equally over the teams (for instance
p=147 and 
there are 15 teams, three teams will be smaller), smaller teams shouldn't play
each other if 
possible. So if team 13, 14 and 15 are smaller match "13 vs 14 vs 15" should be
avoided if 
possible. (While match "13 vs 14 vs ..." can't be avoided since team 13
has to play team 14 at 
least once.)

The rules are ordered according to importance, rule 1 is the most important.

The answer to this problem may be given in any form: group theory, graphs,
algebra ect.
Buy I prefer some kind of pseudocode so I can easily make a Mathematica workbook
or C++ 
application. Of course every little tip is very welcome, it doesn't have to be a
complete 
solution!

Many thanks,
Eric

Comment: Look for *combinatorial designs* and *Steiner systems*. The existence of a Steiner system $S(15,3,2)$ means that your example schedule could be completed in the minimum number of 35 games. But there are extra conditions required to make sure that you can split those 35 games into 7 rounds. I'm fairly sure that this is a well studied variant, but don't remember what it's called.

Comment: In the special case that $t=2$ (so the games are played between pairs of teams) I think the notion of edge coloring of complete graphs may be relevant.  The page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#Examples may be helpful.  (Here the days of the week are used instead of the notion of different types of games $A$, $B$, $C$,... in your problem.)